# Order of validations

Tags: validation, grails, grails-3.0

Is the order of how validations are executed always the same? How is it ordered?

For these constraints:

```
static constraints = {
   A ...
   B ...
   C ...
}
```

Is it always true that they will be executed in the order A -> B -> C?

**Why do I need it?**

In the validation of **A** I need to check against a db that an identifier exists. If not I would fail the validation. **B** and **C** depend on the value looked up.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ? whats ur requirement ?

Comment: Does it matter ?

Comment: Guys, I've edited the question. See the new section `Why do I need it?`

Comment: Without the details about your exact constraints it's going to be difficult to give you a 100% accurate answer, as there are many factors (for example, shared constraints) which may or may not modify the order in which they are applied.  My suggestion would be to read the source code for the classes in the `org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints` package on github (https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/) and apply your requirements. All things being equal, if you are just doing basic constraints then the answer is Yes, They are applied in A,B,C order.

Comment: Thx @JoshuaMoore it is helpful. I am validating just basic constraint.

Comment: Bad luck @JoshuaMoore it doesn't keep the order not even for basic constraints. Maybe I should have said I am using a custom validator `{val, obj -> ...}`.

Comment: @zatziky Then you are right, custom validators are not one of the "basic" constraints I was talking about. They are evaluated in a different order. Again, you can read through the source code and determine the order they will be evaluated in your situation.

Comment: @zatziky Also, you might consider the fact this order isn't guaranteed and could change from version to version of Grails. Since you're using a custom validator already, why not just have that one validator validate all the dependent fields? That seems like the correct approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact the order isn't guaranteed by Grails itself and could change between versions any dependancy you make upon it will be fragile at best.

This would suggest you're approaching the problem incorrectly.

Given your situation of fields B and C depending on A the right solution would be to implement a custom validator for A which considers all three.

Something like this:

```
a(validator: { val, obj, errors ->
  if (!val ...) { 
    errors.rejectValue('a', 'whatever.problem')
    return
  }
  if (!obj.b ...) { 
    errors.rejectValue('b', 'some.other.problem')
    return
  }
  if (!obj.c ...) { 
    errors.rejectValue('c', 'another.problem')
    return
  }
})
```

Comment: Josh, it still doesn't solve the problem. The B and C are validated before A but they are dependent on A. I split the validation and `A.validate()`, `B.validate()` and `C.validate()`. Grails approach seems very limiting to me in this case (and other cases too ;).

Comment: Remove the other validations you have on B and C and encapsulate them in the validation of A so that they can be done dependently (e.g. single unit of work).

Comment: So if my object has fields A, B and C you recommend to have a validator for A only and test the other 2?

Comment: If B and C should only be tested after A has passed then, yes, that's the way I would approach it. Test all of them in one custom validator on A. You can control the errors raised and which field to reject as well via `errors`.

Comment: Josh, I'll accept the answer but I don't agree with putting validations of the other fields to A. If requierments on the Domain changes and new fields may come it can mix up the order. Then I find it better to keep the validations separately as I proposed - `*.validate()`. Thank you for help.